# Visual Studio Code python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I want to make .py as standard filetype in Visual Studios Code, so I don´t have to search "Python" every time I save files. I only learn python so it would be very nice.

Comment: "so I don\`t have to search "Python" every time I save files"—what does this mean? I've never had to search "Python" to save a file.

Comment: If you want to save a file as .py you have to select python in the endless options. Sorry that i can´t explain that good, my english isn´t the best

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand. Why can't you just type `file.py`? Maybe a screenshot would help.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you're on Windows and trying to choose the file type when going through the Save dialog. You actually don't have to change the file type; all it does is save you from having to type `.py` at the end of your file name. If you write the whole file name out with file extension then VS Code will not add the default `.txt` file type extension.